# Create a Button that Opens a new Tab in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a game. For that game, there should be a "Play" Button (already added) and a rules button (the one I am trying to add). For some reason, when I try to add the rules button, it never shows up in the screen. Inside the rules tab I just want to add the rule content of the game. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
package com.example.jaxafx_practice;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
//import com.example.jaxafx_practice.Playscene.playscence;


public class Main extends Application {
    Scene StartScene;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary) throws IOException {

        // ********Start scene************
        Button PlayButton = new Button("Play");
        PlayButton.setMinWidth(55);
        PlayButton.setMinHeight(30);
        
        VBox layout1 = new VBox(250.0);
        layout1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label StartSceneLabel = new Label("Wordle");
         StartSceneLabel.setMinWidth(55);
        StartSceneLabel.setMinHeight(30);
        StartSceneLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        StartSceneLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;");
        layout1.getChildren().addAll(StartSceneLabel, PlayButton);
        primary.setTitle("Start screen");
        layout1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#800000");
        HBox user_interface=new HBox();


        // Creates Start scene
        StartScene = new Scene(layout1, 500, 750.0);

        // ********Start scene************



        //????????Play scene?????????????
        Playscene playscene = new Playscene();
        //????????Play scene?????????????

        //Create the word to be guessed
        Choose_word Choose_word = new Choose_word();
        String wordToGuess = Choose_word.getWord();


        //Button actions
        PlayButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
            primary.setScene(playscene.playscence());
            primary.setTitle("Game Screen");});
        primary.setScene(StartScene);
        primary.show();
        playscene.enterButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
            String userWord=playscene.guessField.getText();
            if(userWord.length()==4)
                {playscene.displayWord(userWord.toLowerCase(),wordToGuess);
                playscene.count+=1;}
        });
        primary.setScene(StartScene);
        primary.show();
    }
    public static void main() {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you tried to add a rules button?  I don’t see any code that tries to add a rules button.

Comment: What is `Playscene`? Why do you set the scene of `primary` to one thing, and then immediately replace it with another scene?

Answer (score 0):

If this line

```
layout1.getChildren().addAll(StartSceneLabel, PlayButton);
```

is where you add the rules button, my guess it's because your layout1 gap is huge. The spacing your suggesting is 250. So adding another component in this list might exceed your stage size. For a test, change

```
VBox layout1 = new VBox(250.0);
```

to

```
VBox layout1 = new VBox(25.0);
```

And then add your button again. I'm guessing this is the issue because like @VGR said, the button isn't there, nor do you have a tabpane yet.